# Calling a Classes' Method From Another Class in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

If I have a document class:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {

        }            
        public function SomeRandomMethod():void {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I call SomeRandomMethod from here:

```
package {
    public class AnotherClass {
        public function AnotherClass() {

        }            
        public function AnotherRandomMethod():void {
            /* I need to use SomeRandomMethod here */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. One way would be to pass a reference of the document class to the constructor of the other class:

```
package {
    public class AnotherClass {
        private var _doc:Main
        public function AnotherClass(doc:Main) {
            _doc = doc;        
        }            
        public function AnotherRandomMethod():void {
            _doc.SomeRandomMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

or to the function itself

```
package {
    public class AnotherClass {
        public function AnotherClass() {

        }            
        public function AnotherRandomMethod(doc:Main):void {
            doc.SomeRandomMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use a singleton design pattern by declaring a global static variable and assigning the document class to it. Although singletons are regarded as an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). For example:

```
package {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;

        public class Main extends MovieClip {

            public static var instance:Main;

            public function Main() {
                instance = this;
            }            
            public function SomeRandomMethod():void {

            }
        }
}
```

then

```
package {
    public class AnotherClass {
        public function AnotherClass() {

        }            
        public function AnotherRandomMethod():void {
            Main.instance.AnotherRandomMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way would be to make use of the Service Locator pattern (although some view it as an anti-pattern too). http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html

Comment: Note that the passing reference to the function itself code isn't right.  It would look like this:  public function set functionToCall(value:Function):void { _functionToCall = void;}                           public function callFunction():void {  _functionToCall();}

Comment: @Amy Blankenship I wasn't trying to create a callback, rather, I meant that the class could either be stored as a class member variable in the constructor or as a local variable in the function itself. But yes, using a callback is another way :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I thought you were saying that you could pass a reference to the function itslf, not pass a reference to the Class to the function itself.