# Passing Main class as this to another class - gives inaccessible reference

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I have 2 classes in my ActionScript project; Main and ContentManager. I wish to pass Main to ContentManager because I want to first instantiate Main, pass control to a method in ContentManager after which control should return to Main.

I do this within Main's constructor by instantiating

```
contentManager = new ContentManager(this);
```

Inside Content Manager's constructor

```
public class ContentManager(_main:Main) {
    this.main = _main;
}
```

And later

```
this.main.setData(data);
```

In Main, setData is

```
public function setData(data:Object):void
{
    versionData = data;
}
```

I am getting a compiler warning that I find strange. Flash Builder auto-completes setData for me inside ContentManager suggesting it is able to see it via this.main. And I am also able to access vars in main during run, e.g.

```
main.somePublicVar = "foo";
```

But calling setData as a method gives:

```
Attempted access of inaccessible method setData through a reference with static type Main.
```

I've since tried a couple of other calls:

```
main.toString();
main.addChild(null);
main.setData(null);
```

The first 2 work fine, the 3rd, my one, fails with the error. Utterly lost.

Cheers

Comment: I'm no ActionScript expert, but passing your `Main` class into your other classes seems the wrong way around. Shouldn't you be instantiating your `ContentManager` in `Main` and calling its public methods, letting `Main` control the show? Two-way dependencies are usually an indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: What he said above, plus: your error method says you're calling a method named `showSubMenu()`, but you don't show us that code.

Comment: I do instantiate ContentManager in Main and call methods on it. However, I need ContentManager to call back to Main. I have tried the custom Event method and dispatching/listening but that fails too with the event not being detected by Main.

Comment: Also, this answer suggests 2 of the methods I have tried - passing Main as a reference, and singleton, same error in both cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302584/calling-a-classes-method-from-another-class-in-flash

Comment: A custom event is the right approach to take here. You should concentrate on figuring out why your event isn't being picked up.

Comment: The error method suggests that maybe your method is private or protected. Are you _sure_ you copied and pasted the code?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure the method was public. Other public methods that come with MovieClip (its parent) were fine. Just my methods. I persevered with net.uk.sweet's suggestion (which I had tried before without success) and found why it was not. The custom event/dispatch/listen was the solution that worked in the end. I am still annoyed though that I did not get to the bottom of passing the document class reference!

Answer (score 0):

As per net.uk.sweet, a custom event + dispatch/listen worked. Listening had to be done ON the contentManager instance which is where I had gone wrong with the approach before, so that it is added to the display list. I added my data into my custom event class so I could access it by the listen callback function. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you have probably declared the function as a setter:

```
public function set setData(data:Object):void
{
    versionData = data;
}
```

And since you are calling it like `main.setData(data)` instead of `main.setData = data` you are getting that error.

Could this be the case?!